# When $\gcd(P(x),Q(x))\bmod R(x)=\gcd(P(x) \bmod R(x),Q(x) \bmod R(x))$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Let's $P,Q\in\mathbb K[x]$, with $\mathbb K$ a finite field.

> On what necessary and sufficient condition on $R \in \mathbb K[x]$ is it :
> $\gcd(P(x),Q(x))\bmod R(x)=\gcd(P(x) \bmod R(x),Q(x) \bmod R(x))$ ?

PS : $Q(x) \bmod R(x)$ is the remainder of the Euclidean division of $Q(x)$ by $R(x)$.

Motivation : [Root of polynomials in a finite field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420481/root-of-polynomials-in-a-finite-field)

Comment: A sufficient condition for divisibility of r.h.s. by l.h.s. is $\gcd(P(x),Q(x))\mid R(x)$.

Comment: max(deg(Q), deg(P)) <deg(R), too